# Docker seems to be migrating database on the server instead of migrating on RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I apologize if my question seems trivial but I am a total noob when it comes to deploying my rails app.

I'm trying to deploy my app using docker on elastic beanstalk. But the deployment fails on the db migration.
I get this message: 
`Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch:  directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`
Am I right thinking that docker is trying to connect locally to postgresql?

I don't see how to tell docker to connect to RDS as my database.yml file is already pointing at my rds database.
Also here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM seapy/ruby:2.2.0

RUN apt-get update

# Install nodejs
RUN apt-get install -qq -y nodejs

# Intall software-properties-common for add-apt-repository
RUN apt-get install -qq -y software-properties-common

# Install Nginx.
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -qq -y nginx
RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx

# Add default nginx config
ADD nginx-sites.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# Install foreman
RUN gem install foreman

# Install the latest postgresql lib for pg gem
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes libpq-dev
# Install paperclip dependencies
RUN apt-get install -qq -y  ImageMagick    

# Copy gemfile and bundle in temporary
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install -j 4

# Copy app and precompile assets
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV RAILS_ENV production
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# Nginx
ADD nginx-sites.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

EXPOSE 80
CMD bundle exec rake db:migrate && foreman start -f Procfile
```

And my database.yml file:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf-8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  hostname: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help but I couldn't find a relevant fix yet,

Best,

Thomas

Comment: If I SSH into the instance ... I am able to run something like this ... `docker run aws_beanstalk/current-app RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE= XXX DB_NAME=XXX DB_USERNAME= XXX DB_PASSWORD= XXX DB_HOSTNAME= XXX DB_PORT=5432 bundle exec rake db:migrate` ... which actually runs the migration on RDS.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might get into the same issue, this is not related to docker but to active_records and means your rails app can not connect to your RDS database.
In my case the issue was specifying a 'hostname' instead of 'host'within the database.yml file.